# Excel IF function help wanted

Tags: excel

I can't upload the picture don't have enough points but this is the link [Pic](http://i64.tinypic.com/2mrebts.png)

I used this formula
    =IF(E43>12,"1","0.5")

The thing is I'm trying to make this IF function work...
**I'd like it to do this 
if in E43 says 0.1-11.59 to write in F43 0.5,
if in E43 says 12-23.59 to write in F43 1,
if in E43 says 24-47.59 to write in F43 2... etc.
In E43 is hours I got everything else sorted but this is a problem...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably the most straight forward answer, but it can get tedious to type out. Don't forget to set it greater or EQUAL to or less than or EQUAL to or your statement will fail at the low and high ranges. Set F43 equal to this... =IF(AND(11.59>=E43,E43>=0.1),0.5,IF(AND(23.59>=E43,E43>=12),1,IF(AND(47.59>=E43,E43>=L24),2,"Greater than 47")))

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this. If the value in F43 is uniformly based on E43, you could use a formula like

```
=CEILING(E43/23.999,0.5)
```

But if the value in F43 isn't uniform (like your example of 24-47.59 = 2) then you can either:

1)

Write a long nested if statement with several AND() functions (i.e. AND(E43>=24,E43<=47.59), or

2)

write a table of vlookup values i.e.

0  | 0.5

12 | 1

24 | 2

and the formula

```
=VLOOKUP(C7,$C$12:$D$14,2,TRUE)
```